# Why is this answer incorrect?

Tags: linear-regression

I calculated an answer in accordance with the provided formula.  The first try, utilizing X2 yielded -0.37 and that was correct, however, on this next try, utilizing X1, which yielded 0.31 was marked as incorrect.  Can someone please tell me why that is the case?

Posted below was my Octave code that generated my answer:

```
X1 = 7921
midterm_avr = mean([7921,5184,8836,4761])
midterm_range = range([7921,5184,8836,4761])
poly_regress = (X1 - midterm_avr) / midterm_range
sprintf('%.*f', 2, ((X1 - midterm_avr) / midterm_range))
```

This is the result that I received:

```
X1 =  7921
midterm_avr =  6675.5
midterm_range =  4075
poly_regress =  0.30564
ans = 0.31
```

Comment: Here is the posted question:[1]:  https://webzest.com/wrongAns.jpg

Comment: that question uses terminology I'm not familiar with...  but why are you using the `mean` of the squared values?  it talks about using `min` and `max` of `x_1`